# why I get undefined value instead my input value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in JavaScript and I have a problem, it'll be great if someone could help me.
I'm trying to write something from one `<p>` to `h4`.
my code is:

```js
function ok() {
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
}
```

```html
<label id="label">your text is:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" />
<p id="name" style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"></p>
<button type="submit" id="click" onclick="ok()">click</button>
<h4 id="out" style="font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;"></h4>
```

but when I'm doing it I get `undefined`.
If someone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong it'll be great.

Comment: `document.getElementById("name")` refers to your `p` element with `id="name"` - can you elaborate as to how you came to the conclusion that it should have a `value` attribute...? Your `input` element seems to be what you're after, but it's unclear how you got to the idea that it has an `id` at all, let along one that matches the string `name`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

It is giving undefined because `<p>` element is empty and you are using `.value` you need to use `.innerHTML` so that is why it is returning undefined.

I changed your code a little bit you can see I am fetching values from the input tag and displaying them in p tag and h4 tag.

```js
function ok()
{
document.getElementById("out").innerHTML=document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=document.getElementById("inputname").value;
}
```

```html
<label id="label">your text is:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="inputname"/>
<p id="name" style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"></p>
<button type="submit" id="click" onclick="ok()">click</button>
<h4 id="out" style="font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;"></h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the wrong element. It's trying to get the value of `<p>`. But `<p>` has no value.

The `id="name"` attribute must be in the input element.

In this way:

```
<input id="name" type="text"/>
<p style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give a `id` to `input` then receive value of that:

```js
function ok() {
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").value;
}
```

```html
<label id="label">your text is:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<p id="name" style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"></p>
<button type="submit" id="click" onclick="ok()">click</button>
<h4 id="out" style="font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;"></h4>
```